# VB2013 and MySql String is not replacing with TextBox text

Tags: mysql, vb.net, string, variables

Could you guys help me? I am trying to add a text as string to from a textbox into a String Variable. I have done this several times, but this time it has stumped me.

It is referring a different form from inside a module. The string reports no value when the code is run. Text Box code here:

```
Public Sql_Add_String2 As String = "INSERT INTO clientlist (ClientCode) VALUES '" & AddClient.txt_CCode.Text.ToString & "';"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the value of the `Sql_Add_String2` string when you are declaring the variable and if you want the value to be dynamically set via textbox value you will need to set the value later. Essentially `Sql_Add_String2` is building the insert string with the value of the `AddClient.txt_CCode` textbox as it is at the start of your application which I am guessing is just a blank string `""`. Try setting the value right before you need to use it.

Module code:

```
Public Sql_Add_String2 As String = ""
```

Whenever you are going to use `Sql_Add_String2` make sure to add this line in front of it:

```
Sql_Add_String2 = "INSERT INTO clientlist (ClientCode) VALUES '" & AddClient.txt_CCode.Text.ToString & "';"
```

Comment: I cannot believe I have been stupid. I expected the system to update itself with values when the variable was called... Many Thanks for setting me straight.